# Alternate approach for finding Minimum value of the below function

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

If $M (x)$ = max ($4-x$, ($\frac{\sqrt x^{3}}{\sqrt3^3}$) )  , $0< x \leq 4$ find minimum value of $M(x)$ in $(0 ,4]$.

> what i did was first of all we need to find the x possible values for which $4-x$ is greater than the other given in the $M(x)$ function. Similarily for other .  By solving two inqualities we would get the where x lies for each of them as a maximum . But after one finds those values and also the equality case , we would need to check at every point where function changes its form and also at end points . Is there a another approach to this without needing to consider case work and then checking for values at some critical points ?

Comment: Have you tried sketching the functions?

Comment: No thats why i didnt solve uaing the solution posted below @DatBoi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of those unusual Calculus problems that is best attacked without Calculus.

At $x=3,$ you have that $\displaystyle (4-x) = 1 = \left[\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{3}}\right]^3.$

For $x < 3,$ the Max function will be controlled by 
$(4-x) > 1.$

For $x > 3,$ the Max function will be controlled by 
$\displaystyle \left[\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{3}}\right]^3 > 1.$

Therefore, the minimum value of $(1)$, which can not be improved in the interval $0 \leq x < 4,$ is achieved at $x=3.$

Comment: I recall that the teacher in mit ocw calculus always said the calculus is actually the easy part.

Comment: @AlexWei Not for this problem.  For this problem, the easy approach was to examine the values for $x \in \{0.01,1,2,3,4\}$, and then just use intuition.  This analogizes to the suggestion of DatBoi, following your posting, of **manually** graphing the two functions.

Comment: Yes. Good suggestion about mannully graphing.

Comment: @AlexWei You can't really use Calculus, on something like Max$[f(x),g(x)]$, until you first nail down the interval where $f(x) < g(x)$ and the interval where $f(x) > g(x).$  However, once you do that, for this particular problem, it is game over anyway, the problem is solved.

Comment: The calculus part for me in this question is to notice the slope(derivative). The rest fall into the other part.

Comment: Forgot about this beautiful trick , thanks @user2661923